# Passing an argument to a PSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a PSSession.

```
$value1 = someValue
$session = New-PSSession $serverList 

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Start-Job -Name jobName1 -ScriptBlock {
  param([string] $value1)
  Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\someLocation -Name "someName" -Value $value1 #"hardcodeValue"
} -Args $value1

$done = Invoike-Command -Session $session -Command {Wait-Job -Name jobName1}

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

I'm expecting "someValue" to be applied to the Registry on the remote server. If I use "hardcodeValue", instead of $value1, the Registry is updated.

Comment: Can you explain why the need for invoking a Job inside of Invoke-Command ?

Comment: As I understand, I need to use Invoke-Command to start the command in the PSSessions, and Start-Job so I can use Wait-Job for them to complete.

Comment: You have nested scriptblocks. You set a param section for the internal scriptblock, but not the outer scriptblock. You then pass an argument to the inner scriptblock, but not the outer one. The outer scriptblock never has `$value1` defined, you need to pass it in as an argument on the `Invoke-Command`, or utilize the `$using:` prefix like `} -Args $using:value1`

Comment: `Invoke-Command` has an `-AsJob` parameter to run things as jobs.

Comment: "and Start-Job so I can use Wait-Job for them to complete." you dont need to. Also, `Invoke-Command` has an `-AsJob` switch for async execution

Answer (score 2):

Your code is overly complicated due to the use of `Start-Job` inside `Invoke-Command`. Simply remove it:

```
$value1 = 'someValue'

Invoke-Command -Session $serverList -ScriptBlock {
    param([string] $value1)

    Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\someLocation -Name 'someName' -Value $value1
} -ArgumentList $value1
```

If you want async execution then you have `-AsJob`:

```
$value1 = 'someValue'

$job = Invoke-Command -Session $serverList -ScriptBlock {
    param([string] $value1)

    Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\someLocation -Name 'someName' -Value $value1
} -ArgumentList $value1 -AsJob

# do other stuff here...

$job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove
```

---

You can also use the `using:` scope modifier which makes it even easier to pass locally defined variables to the remote scope:

```
$value1 = 'someValue'

Invoke-Command -Session $serverList -ScriptBlock {
    Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\someLocation -Name 'someName' -Value $using:value1
}
```